# When using SQL inside SMS it runs correctly, when running from Linq to Sql it fails

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ssms

I have a very mysterious problem with LINQ to SQL that manifests itself at runtime of my application.

When I do this query in Microsoft SQL Management Studio:

`DELETE FROM [DEVICEQUEUE] WHERE DEVICE_ID = 74537638492227750 AND QUEUE_ID =  '16d0b5c4-5ea1-4644-bde2-04bf84e5080b'`

It will nicely dispose of all the effected records.

But when I run the very same query from `DataContext.-databasename-.ExecuteCommand` from C# I get a stacktrace telling me there is a Foreign Key violation (and indeed, there are Foreign Keys added to DEVICEQUEUE the table)

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_DEVICEQUEUE_QUEUE". The conflict occurred in database "x", table "dbo.DEVICEQUEUE", column 'QUEUE_ID'.
The statement has been terminated. # System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException # Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean) # at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
<the rest of the stacktrace>
```

I checked all the data and it is okay (hence the very same command from SQL Management Studio is 100% working), but now I am out of ideas on how to debug this problem. How can I extract more information from Linq to SQL to get a grip on this problem?

Comment: I guarantee you this is nothing to do with LinqToSql and everything to do with data in your database.

Comment: I very well could be, but why is the query running correctly from SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Different ID perhaps, without referenced data? Cascading deletes somewhere?

Comment: You are trying to delete a row that is referenced by another row (may be in different table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be helpful to open **SQL Server Profiler** to see the query that is actually executed. I usually open it through the SQL Server Management Studio, *Tools, SQL Server Profiler* menu item.

After the *Connect to server* dialog, the **Trace Properties** dialog is displayed.

- Select the template **TSQL_Duration** and click **Run**.

Perform the LINQ query and see what query was executed. It will also display the duration in milliseconds.

Optionally, suppose there's a lot of database activity on your server, you could apply some filtering.

In the *Trace Properties* dialog, tick the **Show all columns** and click the **Column Filters**. The *Edit Filter* dialog that pops up allows you to specify your filters. Filtering on the columns **DatabaseName** and **HostName** will come in handy.